# Bucle con acumulador para golang

Tags: bucles, go

Buenas alguien me propria ayudar con el siguiente ejercicio que me pidieron,el cual es un ciclo for que tiene que pedir números por teclado y acumularlos,hasta llegar o superar el numero 100 y mostrarlo en pantalla.. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Hola user324345, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener

Answer (score -1):

Si entendí bien tu ejercicio, el bucle debería detenerse cuando la suma del total de números introducidos sea mayor o igual a 100:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var (
        total int
        actual int
    )

    for total <= 100 {
        fmt.Print("Número: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &actual)

        total += actual
    }

    fmt.Println("\nSe ha llegado o superado el número 100:", total)
}
```

El carácter `\n` inserta un salto de línea, aquí lo utilizo para que la frase «Se ha llegado o superado el número 100:» quede separada de las entradas.

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo

Comment: Si no entiendes la pregunta, puedes realizar preguntas para aclaraciones como comentario, saludos.

Comment: Parece que tengo un talento para perder puntos... Gracias por la aclaración del voto negativo....